# Invalid account details accepts while adding new site account in yodlee live API

Tags: yodlee

I'm using yodlee live API to link the bank transaction details.

Invalid bank account details accepts, when we add new site account in yodlee via live API, For example, the the account details like xxxxx and yyyyy, then the account added successful.

It's normal or any settings to be turned on in yodlee account or API parameters?

How can i validate the account details? while user add new site account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though Yodlee accepts the invalid details/credentials, the account would fail. This would be represented by an Error code such as 402, which would mean that the credentials are wrong.

This is normal setting and teh only way you can validate if the details are right is by checking the status of the account. The error code should be "0" if everything is right.

Hope this helps. You can get more details on error codes under different scenarios @[Error Code](http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes)

Hope this helps

-Vijay

Comment: Hi Vijay,

Thanks for your reply.

The account login is ok. It's seems to be ok. I'm talking about create new site account(bank account).

I'm trying to add new site account (i mean , new bank account) via this below API call.
API call url: [/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1]

While adding, i give the username: **1sdfsdfsdf** and password as : **324df3423**. 
These values are not correct one. But yodlee accepts this invalid details and created successful site account and return a code as: 801.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yodlee doesn't know the username/password entered during add account are correct or not; it has to validate the same with Bank website.

To explain you the process:

When you are adding a particular Bank account, you provides the username/password(it may be correct or incorrect) Yodlee doesn't know and can't validate at the time of submission. Yodlee takes the inputs(username/password) and submits the same to the Bank website(which consumer had selected); meanwhile you'll receive a response from API- addSiteAccount1, which will have the code as 801 (Refresh Never Done and Yodlee is going to update your account).
Once Bank website validate the same and found them incorrect Yodlee return 402 error code(invalid credentials), you need to call [getSiteRefreshInfo](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteRefreshInfo) API to check the same in loops each of 3-4sec.

Comment: Hi Apoorv, ok thanks. Let me check the account status with getSiteRefreshInfo API call.